# Where could I go to find editing services that specialize in RPGs?

Tags: game-design, publishing, agents-of-change

So I have had a [time travel](http://www.kickstarter.com/projects/1790700108/agents-of-change-the-time-travel-rpg) [themed RPG](http://gamerwritings.blogspot.com/search/label/Agents%20of%20Change) successfully kickstarted and am entering the stage where I await feedback from the playtesters. In the meantime, I am searching for editing services that specialize in rpg writing.

Would the editing services by Createspace be sufficient or are there ones out there that the community knows of I could query?

Edit: I altered the question entirely to better fit the rules.

Comment: Regarding initiative, you may find this question helpful: [How do you administer combat without an initiative system?](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/15542/how-do-you-administer-combat-without-an-initiative-system)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There is no such central directory or community. RPGs are largely edited by people who have connections with the designer(s). Whether it's a big game publisher with professional connections to editors and editing agencies, or it's an independent designer who knows a semi-pro game editor on Twitter, the pattern is the same: who you know is how you connect with the people with the talents and skills you're looking for.

Start by considering your social and professional networks. Put out the word that you're looking for an editor. With a Kickstarter behind you, that's a resource you can lean on too – use the buzz around that, and the communications channels you've established during the campaign, to put out word that you want to bring on someone from outside for additional editing.

I know *of* a bunch of people who do game editing professionally, but who I know of doesn't help you, because they're not your connections, and I don't have a strong enough connection to pull on it and connect them to a stranger. Game editors are out there though – go meet them.

Answer (score 6):

Ask other roleplaying game creators for editor references and recommendations. Most will be happy to help you.

Comment: -1 I think this is a bad answer for the format.  You really could answer 90% of the questions on this site with "go ask another GM" or "go ask another player" or whatever - that doesn't make a good answer. He *is* asking other RPG creators - ideally ones using RPG.SE.

Comment: For _this_ question in particular, asking other game designers for references is the right move. See also SevenSidedDie's answer. Cheers.